# Kill the tricks tag

Tags: discussion, tagging

What do we need [tricks](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tricks) for, exactly? I just voted to reject an attempt to create a tag wiki for it, but really I think this tag is absurd.

Comment: I agree. I have untagged the questions tagged (tricks), which will cause the tag to disappear in 1 day unless more questions are tagged with it.

Comment: @AlexBecker: Can the people who downvoted please flesh out why? What in the tag wiki are you against?

Comment: Here is the link to the [suggested edit](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/143465) that dfeuer mentions. I should say that I have told Frank Muer that if someone creates tag, they should also create the tag-wiki. (We had short discussion about the tag in the questions where the tag was created, it continued on meta.)

Comment: @FrankMuer The tag wiki is not for justifying why a tag exists, it is for explaining how the tag is used. I did not reject the tag wiki edit because I think the tag is unnecessary (although I think it is), but because of that.